# Redirect a known folder on subdomain to main site for nginx

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

I have several subdomain based sites in my CMS like:

```
a.site.com
b.site.com
```

All uploaded files are under the `/upload` directory like:

```
site.com/upload/2012/a.jpg
```

But URL's are generated like this: "`/upload/2012/a.jpg`". In this situation, the same image can be accessed at `a.site.com/upload/2012/a.jpg` URL and `b.site.com/upload/2012/a.jpg` URL.

How can I configure nginx to redirect all requests that point to `/upload` to `site.com/upload`. Example:

```
a.site.com/upload/2012/a.jpg => site.com/upload/2012/a.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

adding the following to the config for your subdomains should do the trick if you have a sepperate server block for *.site.com

```
location /upload/ {
  rewrite ^ http://site.com$request_uri permanent;
}
```

if you're catching both site.com and *.site.com in the same server block you need to add an extra if statement to that:

```
location /upload/ {
  if( $host != site.com ) {
    rewrite ^ http://site.com$request_uri permanent;
  }
  # if we get here it's the main site
  # directives for serving http://site.com/upload/ go here
}
```

Comment: my subdomains are not static i can't add this rule to them.

Comment: how is your nginx handling the different domains? One serverblock that catches both the main domain and all subdomains, one serverblock for the main domain and a 2nd one with a "server_name *.site.com;" for the subdomains, something else? In the former case you need an additional if matching on $host around the rewrite, in the second case the block should work as is.

Comment: @cobaco, while this isn't likely matter in this particular case, you may want to add trailing "/" in location to don't match "/uploadedfiles" and so on, and trailing "?" in rewrite after $request_uri to avoid query string duplication.

Comment: Good point about the slash. 
Where would the duplication come from? you're explictly telling nginx what to rewrite to, and including $args only once (indirectly as $request_uri is the orignal request including any arguments)

Comment: @cobaco, from [official docs](http://nginx.org/r/rewrite): _If a replacement string includes the new request arguments, the previous request arguments are appended after them. If this is undesired, putting a question mark at the end of a replacement string avoids having them appended_

Answer (score 1):

Nginx not generate urls. It is a web server. It answer to requests like `http://site.com/upload/2012/a.jpg`.

So you can change relative links `/upload/2012/a.jpg` in you html code to absolute `http://site.com/upload/2012/a.jpg` and not change nginx config. Or change nginx config for subdomains and nginx will send same image for `http://site.com/upload/2012/a.jpg` and `http://a.site.com/upload/2012/a.jpg` and `http://b.site.com/upload/2012/a.jpg` requests.

If you prefer change config you have to create unificated config for all subdomains. [Because](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

> When searching for a virtual server by name, if name matches more than one of the specified variants, e.g. both wildcard name and regular expression match, the first matching variant will be chosen, in the following order of precedence

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  *.site.com;

    location ^~ /upload {
         root   /real/path/to/upload/; 
         ...
    }

}
```

[location directive manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)